# Jquery blur event is not working

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm making a form and validating using JQuery. At the end of the validation I put the code:

```
$(":input").not("#submit").blur(function() {
                    if(!$(":input").hasClass('invalido') && !$(":input").hasClass('unset') && $("#politica").is(':checked')){
                        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                        $('#submit').css('backgroundColor', 'rgb(226, 1, 122)');
                        $('#submit').attr('value', 'enviar');
                    }else{
                        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $('#submit').css('backgroundColor', 'rgb(237, 141, 177)');
                        $('#submit').attr('value', 'enviar se activará al validar todos los campos');
                    }
```

That's working ok except when the user for example check/uncheck the checkbox at the end, because it's not an input field.

I'd like to check the submit button state with something like (keyUp/check/select any option of the select box). In that way no matter if the user check/uncheck the checkbox, select an option or blur a text field at the end. Do you have any idea?

I mean any way to check in 'real time' the status of the entire form and just enable the submit form when everything is right.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A checkbox isn't an input field?  Or do you mean that a `select` isn't an input field?  Technically neither is a `textarea`, so if you have one of those it would require a change to the selector as well.

In any event, perhaps `blur` isn't the right event.  If the `checkbox` technically never receives focus by the browser, it would never blur.  It will, however, change.  And it's usually safe to assume that the validation state of the form can only be affected when a form element *changes*.  (It can change without blurring, and it can blur without changing.)

So try using the `change` event instead:

```
$("input, select, textarea").not("#submit").change(function() {
    // validation logic, enabling or disabling a button
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [:input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector is fine. You will have better luck with the `change` event instead of `blur`. The `blur` event [doesn't fire](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html) on checkboxes and radio buttons in some browsers.

```
$(":input").not("#submit").change(function() {
    // code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I decided to use click on submit. That wasn't what I wanted but that's the best option. I'd liked to difference when the submit button is enabled or disabled but I decided to choose that option because it works definitely better. Thanks to everybody one more time.
Best regards